# Como enviar por POST solo los elementos seleccionados?

Tags: php, post

Quiero enviar por el método POST solo los datos que están seleccionados incluyendo el nombre del insumo y la cantidad,  como podría hacer? estoy trabajando con PHP y HTML, los datos los cargo de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo de form
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo has generado el html? Muestra el código para que veamos cómo es tu formulario. Lo correcto sería que te llegara un Array de items de cada fila. Así podrías recorrerlo y ver que está chequeado.

Comment: edite mi publicación mira brother, estoy metiendo dentro del form una tabla donde tengo los datos, esos datos los estoy cargando de la BD

Answer (score -1):

Suponiendo que los elementos los tenés en un `<form>`, cuando hacés el `submit` del formulario solo se enviarán en el request aquellos elementos que no tengan el atributo 'disabled'.

Por lo tanto si no querés que se envíe un dato, colocale disabled al elemento de entrada antes de enviarlo.

Se me ocurre que podes hacer esto cuando haces la validación del formulario en javascript.

Por otro lado, si lo estás enviando con ajax, bueno en ese caso tenes control total de los que se manda y lo que no así que es solo cuestión de determinar si agregas la variable al POST o no.